# QT 5 [ error: QtGui/QApplication: No such file or directory]

Tags: c++, qt5

I am using Qt5. I wrote the following code:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <Qlabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
QApplication prog(argc, argv);
Qlabel *label = new Qlabel("gametime!");
label->show();

return prog.exec();
}
```

the following problem occurs:-

> error: QtGui/QApplication: No such file or directory

Comment: show your .pro.

Comment: change `#include <QtGui/QApplication>` to `#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>`

Answer (score 2):

`QApplication` is part of the Qt5 **Widgets** library (not the **GUI** library, which provides lower-level facilities).

Add `QT += widgets` to your `.pro` file, and change

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
```

to

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
```

(You should be able to reduce to just `<QApplication>`, as QMake will normally add the necessary include paths based on the libraries specified in the `QT` variable.)